# Dynamically select last row of a worksheet and enter selected data into an existing table in a word doc

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Hi I’m a nube to excel VBA and would appreciate it greatly if someone could assist me in this issue.
I’ve spent over 5 days researching and reading, trying to solve this issue and can’t get the required result can anyone please help.
I’m using a userform to submit data to a worksheet then the above vba to open a word template, dynamically select the last line of the worksheet and enter selected cell data into a pre-existing table at various placeholder bookmarks within a word template.
The code always pastes the data above the table and not in it.
Here's the code i'm using

```
Sub testdata()
'declare variables
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
'declare variable for save  format
    Dim savename As String
'declare fileext type for differnt versions of word
    Dim fileext As String
    'start word
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'make it visible and activate it
    With wdApp
'uncomment 2 lines below to see word on screen
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
'opens a word doc
        .Documents.Add "C:\xxx\xxx\excel_project\test.docx"
 'collect data range ref number
         Range("A1").End(xlDown).Copy
'selects  the item bookmark in word template
         .Selection.GoTo What:=-1, Name:="Item"
'paste into word doc
        .Selection.Paste
 'test version type of word
        If .Version <= 11 Then
            fileext = ".doc"
        Else
            fileext = ".docx"
        End If
'saves doc with specific timedate name
        savename = "C:\xxx\xxx\excel_project\test" & _
        Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss") & fileext
'changes save as method depended on word version
        If .Version <= 12 Then
            .ActiveDocument.SaveAs savename
        Else
            .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 savename
        End If
'closes the doc
        .ActiveDocument.Close
'closes word
        .Quit
     End With
End Sub
```

One source of help suggested using
`

```
Sub FnBookMarkInsertAfter()
   Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc
   Dim objRange
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\xxx\xxx\excel_project\test.docx")
   objWord.Visible = True
    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("item").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter ("..........I will be added AFTER bookmark")
End Sub
```

`
This places the string of text into the table and I can’t find a way to make it dynamically select the last row and hence the required data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: To clarify the objective: You are trying to insert rows at the end of a table that is marked with a bookmark "item"?

Comment: Hi EngJon, no what I.m trying to achieve is insert data from cells in a worksheet date, name etc into an existing table 2x3 in a 2010 word template, thanks for the answer below I.ll try it out tonight and see if it gives the desired results, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code inserts an extra row below the last row of a table. The bookmark "Item" must be located inside your table, then this will work. The strings col1 and col2 are inserted in the cells of the new row. Hope this helps you.

```
Sub InsertTextAtEndOfTable()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim col1, col2 As String
    col1 = "TitleColContent"
    col2 = "ValueColContent"
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Item"
    Dim tabSize As Integer
    tabSize = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Select
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To tabSize - 1
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Next i
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow
    Selection.TypeText col1
    Selection.MoveRight
    Selection.TypeText col2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```